# Not getting any data from select query

Tags: postgresql, go

When I try the following function I just get empty or null values from my postgres db. Eveything I have found here and in both golang and postgres documentation is not helping. I am sure it is something simple I am overlooking. What am I missing?(if I have provided enough info)

```
// GetAllAPI gets all records from db
func (m *postgresDBRepo) GetAllAPI() string {

    rows, err := m.DB.Query("select * from recipesnonjson")
    helpers.CheckError(err)

    var test []models.MealsSearch

    for rows.Next() {
        var recipe models.MealsSearch

        rows.Scan(
            &recipe.IDMeal,
            &recipe.StrMeal,
            &recipe.StrDrinkAlternate,
            &recipe.StrCategory,
            &recipe.StrArea,
            &recipe.StrInstructions,
            &recipe.StrMealThumb,
            &recipe.StrTags,
            &recipe.StrYoutube,
            &recipe.StrIngredient1,
            &recipe.StrIngredient2,
            &recipe.StrIngredient3,
            &recipe.StrIngredient4,
            &recipe.StrIngredient5,
            &recipe.StrIngredient6,
            &recipe.StrIngredient7,
            &recipe.StrIngredient8,
            &recipe.StrIngredient9,
            &recipe.StrIngredient10,
            &recipe.StrIngredient11,
            &recipe.StrIngredient12,
            &recipe.StrIngredient13,
            &recipe.StrIngredient14,
            &recipe.StrIngredient15,
            &recipe.StrIngredient16,
            &recipe.StrIngredient17,
            &recipe.StrIngredient18,
            &recipe.StrIngredient19,
            &recipe.StrIngredient20,
            &recipe.StrMeasure1,
            &recipe.StrMeasure2,
            &recipe.StrMeasure3,
            &recipe.StrMeasure4,
            &recipe.StrMeasure5,
            &recipe.StrMeasure6,
            &recipe.StrMeasure7,
            &recipe.StrMeasure8,
            &recipe.StrMeasure9,
            &recipe.StrMeasure10,
            &recipe.StrMeasure11,
            &recipe.StrMeasure12,
            &recipe.StrMeasure13,
            &recipe.StrMeasure14,
            &recipe.StrMeasure15,
            &recipe.StrMeasure16,
            &recipe.StrMeasure17,
            &recipe.StrMeasure18,
            &recipe.StrMeasure19,
            &recipe.StrMeasure20,
            &recipe.StrSource,
            &recipe.StrImageSource,
            &recipe.StrCreativeCommonsConfirmed,
            &recipe.DateModified,
        )
        helpers.CheckError(err)

        fmt.Println()
        test = append(test, recipe)
    }

    recipeByte, err := json.MarshalIndent(test, "", "\t")
    helpers.CheckError(err)

    fmt.Println(string(recipeByte))

    return (string(recipeByte))

}
```

This is the returned JSON

```
{
                "idMeal": "",
                "strMeal": "",
                "strDrinkAlternate": null,
                "strCategory": "",
                "strArea": "",
                "strInstructions": "",
                "strMealThumb": "",
                "strTags": "",
                "strYoutube": "",
                "strIngredient1": "",
                "strIngredient2": "",
                "strIngredient3": "",
                "strIngredient4": "",
                "strIngredient5": "",
                "strIngredient6": "",
                "strIngredient7": "",
                "strIngredient8": "",
                "strIngredient9": "",
                "strIngredient10": "",
                "strIngredient11": "",
                "strIngredient12": "",
                "strIngredient13": "",
                "strIngredient14": "",
                "strIngredient15": "",
                "strIngredient16": null,
                "strIngredient17": null,
                "strIngredient18": null,
                "strIngredient19": null,
                "strIngredient20": null,
                "strMeasure1": "",
                "strMeasure2": "",
                "strMeasure3": "",
                "strMeasure4": "",
                "strMeasure5": "",
                "strMeasure6": "",
                "strMeasure7": "",
                "strMeasure8": "",
                "strMeasure9": "",
                "strMeasure10": "",
                "strMeasure11": "",
                "strMeasure12": "",
                "strMeasure13": "",
                "strMeasure14": "",
                "strMeasure15": "",
                "strMeasure16": null,
                "strMeasure17": null,
                "strMeasure18": null,
                "strMeasure19": null,
                "strMeasure20": null,
                "strSource": null,
                "strImageSource": null,
                "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
                "dateModified": null
        }
]
```

Comment: `rows.Scan` returns an error but you are not assigning it to a variable, so the subsequent error check is checking the old error returned by `m.DB.Query`.

Comment: By the way `helpers.CheckError(err)` is a bad pattern. I assume you are invoking `panic` from it. Don't do that. Instead you should handle the error value properly, using the idiomatic `if err != nil { return err }` pattern. And if you are not invoking `panic` from it then that's even worse, then your program's just broken.

Comment: @mkopriva I did not see that it returned an error. That gives me the info I needed. I thought scan was more dynamic. Only reason I tried the helper error handle was because I came across it here in SO. Thank you